# Change to multiline text field background color

Tags: android, eclipse, text, multiline

I put my app multiline text field in eclipse. I want tou change background color of multiline text field. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did You Try This:

```
android:background
```

Comment: yeah. that worked ;) last time i tried "android:background" too but it didn't work. But now it's working. Interesting :D